# How do I find and decouple entities from a certificate when upgrading MS-SQLServer editions?

Tags: sql-server

While in the final throws of upgrading MS-SQL Server 2005 Express Edition to MS-SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition, I came across this error:

> The certificate cannot be dropped because one or more entities are either signed or encrypted using it. To continue, correct the problem...

So, **how do I find and decouple the entities signed/encrypted using this certificate so I can delete the certificate and proceed with the upgrade?**

I'm also kind of expecting/assuming that the upgrade setup will provide a new certificate and re-couple those former entities with it or I'll have to forcibly do so after the setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft forum has the following code snipit to delete the certificates:

```
use msdb   
BEGIN TRANSACTION
declare @sp sysname
declare @exec_str nvarchar(1024)    
declare ms_crs_sps cursor global for select object_name(crypts.major_id) from sys.crypt_properties crypts, sys.certificates certs where crypts.thumbprint = certs.thumbprint and crypts.class = 1 and certs.name = '##MS_AgentSigningCertificate##'    
open ms_crs_sps    
fetch next from ms_crs_sps into @sp    
while @@fetch_status = 0  
begin    
if exists(select * from sys.objects where name = @sp) begin print 'Dropping signature from: ' + @sp set @exec_str = N'drop signature from ' + quotename(@sp) + N' by certificate [##MS_AgentSigningCertificate##]'   
Execute(@exec_str)
if (@@error <> 0)
begin
declare @err_str nvarchar(1024)
set @err_str = 'Cannot drop signature from ' + quotename(@sp) + '. Terminating.'
close ms_crs_sps
deallocate ms_crs_sps
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
RAISERROR(@err_str, 20, 127) WITH LOG
return
end
end
fetch next from ms_crs_sps into @sp
end
close ms_crs_sps
deallocate ms_crs_sps
COMMIT TRANSACTION
go
```

http://forums.microsoft.com/TechNet/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3876484&SiteID=17

I have not tried the script, so please backup your data and system before attempting and update here with results.